# How to i find the count of check boxes is selected?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

In the UI there are 50 check boxes. 
If I selected 20 check boxes. 
How to I find count of 20 is selected?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While asking the question on this forum also mention what you have tried and paste you code. Go through the link on [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium provides the [isSelected method](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isSelected--), which returns whether a checkbox is selected. Then you can use it to filter in only the selected checkboxes.

```
List<WebElement> checkboxes = driver.findElements(...)
List<WebElement> selectedCheckboxes = checkboxes.stream()
                                     .filter(checkbox -> checkbox.isSelected()).collect(Collectors.toList())
Integer numberOfSelectedCheckboxes = selectedCheckboxes.size();
```

Comment: Thank u so much

Comment: Most welcome. Could you mark the question as accepted? It really helps to keep contributors in the site.